# How can you suppress all logging in Cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, appkit

Is there a way to force suppression of *all* logging in a Mac OS X desktop Cocoa app?

Sometimes some part of the system or a plugin (which is out of your control) will log messages on behalf of your application to the console (system.log).

Is there a way to suppress all logging in your application?

Comment: Why? If you want to be able to filter out any log entries that didn't originate from your code, then just add a special tag to your log statements and grep for that.

Comment: There could be many reasons. For example maybe you want to prevent a malicious plugin of your app from flooding the console.

Comment: It seems that you have a case for a direct discussion with Apple Engineering around these pieces; around sand-boxing and around console output.  Suppressing messages from malicious code seems expedient (and I'd probably send it to /dev/null), but just seems the wrong way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@gabe: was just going to suggest something similar - just tried it out, and a simple 'fclose(stderr)' seems to prevent any output.

Answer (score 4):

You could use freopen to change where stdout and sterr point to:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/freopen.html

Comment: I don't think that will affect ASL (which is what NSLog uses).

Answer (score 0):

I've also done this whenever I've needed to redirect console output to a custom view:

```
stderr->_write = RedirectOutputToView;
stdout->_write = RedirectOutputToView;
```

Where RedirectOutputToView has the following prototype:

```
int RedirectOutputToView(void *inFD, const char *buffer, int size);
```